# jQuery Selector to get (nth) element under UNKNOWN DEPTH?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

To select the specific `<div>` (for e.g the `<div>` commented as `<!-- This one!`)
**Please note all of `<..>` elements are unknown elements at all levels, BUT NO `<div>`'s.**

```
<div></div>
<div class="class1">
    <..>
        <..></..>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div> <!-- 3rd-child div, of its parent -->
            <..></..>
            <..>
                <div></div>
                <div></div> <!-- This one! The 2nd-child div, of its parent -->
                <div></div>
            </..>
        </div>
        <div></div>
    </..>
</div>
```

In this scenario, the only logic i can think is:

- ONLY the element type as `<div>`s and the `nth` numbers (among siblings) are KNOWN.
- Middle elements are `unknowns`. Can be `<p>` or `<table>` or `<ul>` whatever, but not `<div>`s again.
- Levels are unknown.

So:

- The target `<div>` is **recursively** located under the `div#class1`
- **It is the `2nd <div>` inside the `3rd <div>` of `div#class1`**

How can i get it?

Comment: What *do* you know about your element? The way I understand your question, your code should work. If you always know the number of `<div>` elements. [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/rsTY6/)

Comment: What do you mean by unknown levels? Could you set up a fiddle that demonstrates your code *not* working?

Comment: UNKNOWN LEVELS means that all `<div>`s can be located under many possible parents above each and between each.

Comment: What if you had a single `div` in one of the levels, and three `div`s in the next? Do you skip the single `div`?

Comment: @DavidHedlund @_@ oh my!!! Is it working????? Gosh!! what is going wrong in my dom? Okie okie sorry every body that is the answer already. David Hedlund, so please put that pattern as a answer again. I'll mark it as answer and remove it from my question. >.< Sorry the pattern is correct. Just my testing DOM is containing falses. :(

Comment: Actually, the selector may not always work. Here's my scenario illustrated with a modified version of @David's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/rsTY6/2 Notice it returns null, because there's no `div` in `div:eq(2)` which matches something different after I introduce the intermediate `div` that wraps all the inner `div`s. I notice my comment hasn't been answered yet, but this may be worth considering.

Comment: @BoltClock But it will work as `$("div.class1 div div:eq(2) div:eq(1)")`. Just need to declare that additional DIV between. Coz, as i said, all DIVs are KNOWN.

Comment: @BoltClock Because, the `eq` selector is ONLY for the same elements, at SAME LEVEL (for siblings). NOT FOR counting the element appearance index top-to-bottom across the whole page.

Comment: You're probably confusing `:eq()` with `:nth-child()`. `:eq()` does not limit itself to matching siblings only.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Will you put that pattern as the answer?

Comment: @BoltClock No, if you use the multiple `eq`s inside the pattern together (like `div:eq(n) div:eq(nn) div:eq(nnn)`) and putting the indexes (n), it will then follow along the hierarchy and their levels. If not, use ONLY ONE `eq` like `div:eq(7)` inside the whole pattern.

Comment: @4lvin: I haven't really answered anything. The code I used is in your question. If there's something else wrong then that haven't been addressed here. If you want help with that you should modify your question to include the relevant information. If you think you can deal with that other issue yourself, then I don't see that anything is being said here. I would rather see that you delete the question, than that I answer it with something nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, i have my own answer already:

```
$("div.class1 div:eq(2) div:eq(1)").html()
```